# Can we compile using only Integers Of Unusual Size?

Tags: compile, big-numbers

I coined [Integers Of Unusual Size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=rodents%20of%20unusual%20size%20%28film%29) to mean "bignum" using [GMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library), the underpinning of *Mathematica's* ability to craft very big numbers.

I have these functions from [this question:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29553/973)

```
ascendingQ[x_] := 3 == Mod[x, 4]
uniqueQ[x_] := 0 != Mod[2 x - 1, 3]
uniqueRank[n_, m_] := Block[{a = If[1 != n && OddQ[n], n - 1, n]},
   (n + IntegerExponent[a, 2]) 2^m - 1]
```

The first two need "bignum" inputs and the third needs "bignum" output

And I have this variation of `countOrbit` which we will use for our research:

```
totalOrbit[x_] := 
 Block[{h = x, t, c = 0, m, n, mt = 0, nt = 0},
  While[1 != h,
   h = (t = -1 + (3/2)^(m = IntegerExponent[h + 1, 2]) (h + 1))/
     2^(n = IntegerExponent[t, 2]);
   mt += m;
   nt += n;
   ];
  c = 2 mt + nt
  ]
```

This needs "bignum" everywhere. When we get a sufficiently frisky `totalOrbit` I will recast `countOrbit`.

After I execute the compiled `totalOrbit`, I get error messages about exceeding machine precision,

```
cto = Compile[{x}, totalOrbit[x]]
```

so, I need a way to indicate that all numbers are "bignums."

Comment: Unfortunately `Compile` supports only machine-size integers, ruling out bignums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `Compile` supports only machine-size integers, ruling out bignums.

Comment: Where is "machine-size integer" defined and documented? Does it vary between machines, and how can I determine what it is on my machine?

Comment: @rogerl Please see `$MaxMachineInteger`. You can get the maximum machine-size integer with `Needs["Developer\`"]; Developer\`$MaxMachineInteger`. `$MinMachineInteger` interestingly enough doesn't exist, but on all even remotely modern architectures (that is, two's complement arithmetic) it would be equal to `-Developer\`$MaxMachineInteger-1`.

Comment: Actually my statement on minimum machine-size integer seems to be false. `Developer\`MachineIntegerQ[-Developer\`$MaxMachineInteger - 1]` returns false, but `Developer\`MachineIntegerQ[-Developer\`$MaxMachineInteger]` returns true. This also corresponds to the documentation... but it's not consistent with how "native" signed types work on real hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that package. And so given this (on my machine, this is $2^{63}-1$, as I expected), can I expect compiled programs with integer arguments to function properly up to this bound? (I realize that this is exactly what the documentation for `Compile` says.)

Comment: Oh, and with respect to the minimum machine-size integer, I think you would expect it to be  equal to   `-$MaxMachineInteger + 1`, not `-$MaxMachineInteger-1`$. But in any case, `-$MaxMachineInteger` returning `True` is indeed unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, `Compile` uses machine numbers only. Also note that `IntegerExponent` is not a compilable function as can be seen from this example:

```
f = Compile[{{in, _Integer, 0}}, IntegerExponent[in]];
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[f]
```

Note the call to `MainEvaluate` in the output. This indicates that the function can not be compiled.

Concerning your top level functions, the switch between bignum and machine integer is opaque in Mathematica. If a calculation needs big integers it will internally switch to such a representation. No action on your part is required for that.