# How should I go about writing more functional and list based code?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I've heard that Mathematica is usually faster when the code is list-based and/or uses a functional paradigm.

I'm still working on getting the hang of this; there are a lot of `If`s and `For`s that I end up using in more complex code that probably shouldn't be there.

In general how do I go about writing more functional and list based code?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Mathematica. It is about functional programming. You basically have to learn to ask the computer what to do and not how to do it. i.e think in a higher abstract level, not implementation level. In addition, you think of functions as objects themselves as well just like data itself. But I think this question belongs to `functional-programming` tag here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming also see wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Comment: @Nasser Thing is, I am reasonably comfortable with Lisp. But Mathematica has its own style, and the problems faced are different. Plus, there are many in-built commands that work well with functional programming or lists.

Comment: So this is like asking: I know OO programming in C++, but how to do OO programming in Java?  well, you need have to learn new syntax and new commands in Java. The concept of OO programming do not change. Only the syntax changes. Same case here with functional programming and different languages. To learn the syntax of Mathematica is a very wide question. At least that is what I think. But you are free to ask anything you want, and others are free to answer :)

Comment: @Nasser, with all due respect, you have some one interested in learning Mathematica and you slap them in their face? I don't get it.

Comment: Is this something you are after?: [alternatives for loops](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)

Comment: @caya I am not slapping anyone. where did this come from? I am simply saying the question is too wide of scope. There are whole library of books published about programming in Mathematica. That is all. But like I said, they are free to ask, any one is free to answer as you did.

Comment: @Nasser, yes, the question is vague but I think answering "go a read books about this" is not a proper reply. What's the point of SE if there are books? I believe the point is helping people to realise what they haven't despite reading. He said "I am reasonably comfortable with Lisp", which tells me that this person is appealing to the wrong paradigm and is reasonable literate in CS; hence my answer to reinforce the due paradigm shift... and my comment to you.

Comment: I think Kuba's link is what you want (especially Verbeia's answer, not Mr.Wizard's). Other than that, as Nasser said, one needs familiarity with functional programming constructs (a purely functional language like Haskell might be easier to learn these concepts than lisp).

Comment: @rm-rf Yep, it is. Hadn't looked at the second answer, and it is really relevant. Thanks :)

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/5) (although this is not exactly a "pitfall" question) and  [Performance tuning in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you come from Lisp, note that Mathematica's approach to list manipulation is not through *deconstruction* operators like CAR and CDR and construction through CONS. And this is also different from traditional functional programming, in which most lists metaphors are actually derived from our old friend Lisp. Mathematica is very different.

Everything in Mathematica is an [expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html) and certainly lists are. So *deconstruction* of expressions in Mathematica is achieved by using mainly pattern matching and some built-in operators. However, you usually don't need to disassemble a list (in the traditional sense) as Mathematica offers built-ins that are *similar* to the functional programming counterparts.

For List manipulation, I find `Fold`, `FoldList`, `Map` and `MapThread` probably the closest to FP - although there are many [others](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html) which would be probably harder to achieve in FP but are built-ins in Mathematica. For example, look at `Partition` or even `Transpose`. Whereas in Lisp a list of lists is just that, Mathematica can transpose it as it were a matrix if you know that all items have the same length.

So, yes, you need to leave the FP list paradigm and embrace expressions in Mathematica!

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting :) I haven't used `Fold` much but I can see how it would be useful here. (Also, I don't "come from" Lisp, I just am comfy with it but I am much more at ease with procedural things).