# EventHandler and Refresh rate

Tags: graphics, eventhandler

Based on the example of the Documentation of MousePosition, Properties and Relations, here is my test code using "MouseDragged" instead of "MouseClicked":

```
DynamicModule[{list = {}},
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[
   Framed@Graphics[{Red, Point[list]}, PlotRange -> 2]
   ]
  , {"MouseDragged" :> AppendTo[list, MousePosition["Graphics"]]}
  ]
 ]
```

Using this, one can drag lines of dots as follows:

[image]

The top line was drawn while moving the mouse very slowly, the bottom line was drawn with a faster mouse movement.

I would now like to add even more points in the bottom line, to be able to have an almost full line, even with fast mouse movements. I have checked out `Refresh`, and `UpdateInterval`, but that didn't change everything.

So: is it possible to track **all** pixel movements of the mouse inside a certain region, to be able to plot **all** points?

As always, thanks for all help!

Comment: What OS do you use? Is your mouse a USB one? The bottleneck COULD be the OS level, as it is said ["by default, the USB polling rate is set at 125hz."](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_Polling_Rate).

Comment: I use Mac OS 10.9 and I use the mouse on the trackpad of the laptop. Do you have different results?

Comment: I'm under win8 and I think I have approached the OS limit in `Dynamic`. But I need more evidence..

Comment: What do you mean with OS limit? I don't follow...

Comment: One OS limit is that the mouse actually jumps from position to position.  You may be capturing all of the positions with your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following seems to be a little faster, most likely because it avoids `AppendTo`.

```
DynamicModule[{list = {}},
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic @ Framed @ Graphics[{Red, list}, PlotRange -> 2], 
   {"MouseDragged" :> 
     (list = Flatten @ {list, Point @ MousePosition["Graphics"]})}]]
```

However, you might find it more to your liking to use lines rather than points. Doing so will allow for nice, smooth lines to be drawn. Here is one way to modify your code to use lines.

```
DynamicModule[{new, old, current = {}, previous = {}},
  EventHandler[
    Dynamic @ Framed @ Graphics[{{Red, previous}, {Black, current}}, PlotRange -> 2], 
    {"MouseDragged" :> 
      (current = 
         Flatten @ {current, Line @ {old, new = MousePosition["Graphics"]}}; 
       old = new),
     "MouseDown" :> (old = MousePosition["Graphics"]; current = {}),
     "MouseUp" :> (previous = Flatten@{previous, current})}]]
```

[image: drawing.png]

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how to increase the mouse polling rate in `Dynamic`-things, but I think it has been doing really well on my computer, which is Windows 8.1 with a regular USB mouse.

Here is a simple code to measure the average polling rate of `Dynamic`:

```
Module[{mplst = {}, time = 10},
       PrintTemporary[DynamicWrapper["Measuring...",
                     mplst = Join[mplst, {MousePosition[]}]
                     ]];
       Pause[time];
       Length[mplst]/time // N
      ]
```

which gives near $100\, \mathrm{Hz}$ result.

This is the result mesured by [tool based on DirectX](http://razerblueprints.net/index.php/View-document-details/18-DirectX-mouserate-checker.html):

[image: true mouse polling rate]

I think it's fair to say `Dynamic` does his job pretty well.

I noticed [there is saying](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_Polling_Rate) that "USB polling rate is set at 125hz" by default. So I will not be surprised if using a high-rate mouse get a better result.

Also, you should be aware that the `AppendTo` might slow down your code when `list` gets big. Please see section 3 in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/17) for detail.

### Update:

Here is a preciser measurement of, I think, the polling rate of `MousePosition` itself without the affection of `Dynamic`.

Put the cursor in the code, keep moving your mouse (but not too fast), meanwhile press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
mplst = {};
time = AbsoluteTiming[Do[
                         mplst = {mplst, MousePosition[]},
                         {10^4}]][[1]];
mplst = mplst // Flatten // Partition[#, 2] &;
freshrate = 10^4/time
```

> 3645.44

It's a HELL of high rate!

But wait... If we take a look into `mplst`, we'll see many of them are duplicates:

```
trueTrackPt = mplst // Split // #[[All, 1]] &;
mouseFreshrate = Length[trueTrackPt]/time
```

> 124.3093

This is really close to the result from the DirextX tool, which could be considered as the *true* rate.

For a much faster mouse movement, the `freshrate` will be greater, but the `mouseFreshrate` will be less.

So I think the mouse polling rate in `Dynamic` might be able to be increased within *Mathematica* (with methods which I haven't found yet), but only with a limited amount. The true bottleneck is still the OS and hardware, to overcome which you'll have to have special drivers and/or a high-rate mouse.

On the other hand, if all you need is smoother trajectory, you can try draw it more slowly, link the sample points with `Line` or `BSplineCurve`, even `Interpolation` them:

```
Graphics[{Lighter[Blue, .4], Thick, Line[trueTrackPt],
          White, Thin, BSplineCurve[trueTrackPt],
          Red, Point[trueTrackPt]},
         Background -> Black]
```

Comment: Thanks, Silvia, for your answer. I get 57. as result with your code, using the trackpad mouse on the Mac machine. Has someone a Mac and could test this too? Thanks!

Comment: In my machine the result depends on whether or not you actually move the mouse. It seems that moving the mouse pointer eats up some cycles ...

Comment: @Gabriel I obtain a similar number on my Mac OS X 10.9 machine with a Bluetooth Magic Mouse but by removing the `Join` from Silvia's code, e.g. using `mplst={mplst,MousePosition[]}` and `Length[Flatten[mplst]]/time` I can increase that to "near 100 Hz".

Comment: @belisarius Here in fact if I put mouse focus out side MMA, the result will be max. And I do think `Dynamic` has not achieved the best performance that `MousePosition` can do.. I'll update some code later.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar I tried your way at first, but it kept crashing my Mathematica, so I have to go the slow way... :( But it's good to know that it's my code rather than `Dynamic` which limits the performance.

Comment: @Silvia There do seem to be some strange differences between OSes though.  PS Tried adding `UpdateInterval->0` to `DynamicWrapper` but it had no noticeable effect.

Comment: @Gabriel Please see my update. Hope it be helpful.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar I think there might be a more effective way to collect the `MousePosition` data. Maybe `Bag`-s can do a better job.

Comment: @Silvia, thanks for the updated code, I'll try this out!