# Understanding execution time in nested loops

Tags: mathematical-optimization, timing

I have the following simple code

```
finalList = {};
For[i = 1, i <= myN - 3, i++,
 For[j = i + 1, j <= myN - 2, j++,
  For[k = j + 1, k <= myN - 1, k++,
   l = RandomInteger[{k + 1, myN}];
   AppendTo[finalList, {i, j, k, l}];
   ]
  ]
 ] // Timing
```

for some value of myN I obtain the following execution times

```
30 0.056
40 0.356
50 1.436
60 4.296
70 12.083
80 43.012
90 116.903
```

that grow much faster than N^3 (it's about N^6 for the first point and it is increasing for the last two points), and I cannot understand why.

Any insight of why this happens?

Comment: It is good to add one sentence what you code is eactly doing. People here don't remember anymore what nested `Fors` are doing :). p.s. Take a look at [$3.2 about `AppendTo` performance](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/5478). You may also be interested in [alternatives to procedural loops](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/5478).

Comment: Don't use `AppendTo`, it is very very slow use `Sow` and `Reap`. And yes as @Kuba hinted at don't use `For` loops.

Comment: At the end: `Tuples`, `Subsets` and friends are quite fast when creating similar lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To demonstrate the time saving using a linked list instead of `AppendTo` :-

```
time1[myN_] := First@Timing[
  finalList = {};
  For[i = 1, i <= myN - 3, i++,
   For[j = i + 1, j <= myN - 2, j++,
    For[k = j + 1, k <= myN - 1, k++,
     l = RandomInteger[{k + 1, myN}];
     AppendTo[finalList, {i, j, k, l}]]]]];

time2[myN_] := First@Timing[
   finalList = {};
   For[i = 1, i <= myN - 3, i++,
    For[j = i + 1, j <= myN - 2, j++,
     For[k = j + 1, k <= myN - 1, k++,
      l = RandomInteger[{k + 1, myN}];
      finalList = {finalList, {i, j, k, l}}]]];
   finalList = Partition[Flatten@finalList, 4]];

ListLinePlot[
 {Map[time1, {30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90}],
  Map[time2, {30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90}]},
InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, time2 is now much similar to a cubic function in the size myN. It's just that is very strange to make a function just to do one thing, but then it is so slow that is better to not use it!

Comment: Probably `ListLogPlot[%, Joined -> True]` in order to see both traces?