# Appending to list without accesing the whole list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, real-time

I'm developing a function that constructs a list with a lot of elements (around 1 million), with each of the elements being a somewhat complicated algebraic expression. I'm doing this by using `AppendTo[outputList,newTerm]` iteratively at each step. I'm noticing the program slows down considerably towards the end steps because it considers `outputList` as a whole and calling this increasingly big list takes a lot of time. I'm trying to figure out if there is any way around this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can explore the `Sow` and `Reap` commands. There are many related posts on this forum about this topic.

Comment: Advantages of linked lists are shown here: [Understanding execution time in nested loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44899/understanding-execution-time-in-nested-loops/44901#44901) and note the best option, 'joined lists', here: [Prepend vs. Append perf in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8455031/879601).

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/134) ?