# Automatic Cuda/CPU code; Fast programme run

Tags: programming, gpu

I have developed my thesis codes by means of Mathematica software in a .nb file format. Despite using the available Parallel code capabilities and doing all the numerical integrations by means of parallel programming; the duration of programme run is so so much high; something like 2 to 3 weeks; which makes the debugging and verification part of the thesis almost unavailable. My question goes to two branches:

1. How can I make my programme more efficient and run faster.
2. I have heard that by applying the Cude or GPU programming; the duration of run will significantly be reduced. How is it possible to automatically change and turn my present codes to a Cude GPU code?

As far as I am facing lack of time for my thesis; answers to my questions and helping me decrease the run duration will be so appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say. As for 1) http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/ or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica

Comment: This question is much too broad to be answerable.  It all depends on what your program does and how it's implemented.  The most likely to be successful solution for a program that runs for 3 weeks is to rewrite it in a low-level language such as C, C++, Fortran, Java, etc.  Using CUDA is not as simple as flipping on a switch.  It requires rewriting the program an it's not always applicable.  To take full advantage of it, you'd need to resort to using C again.

Comment: This question is partially answered in that page but there is no clue to the GPU and Cuda writing there at all.

Comment: Do you perform matrix inversion of large matrices by any chance? It makes a really huge difference whether you have integers of reals in them.

Comment: @user52417 Your CUDA question is essentially: "how can I speed up any Mathematica code using CUDA"?  This is much too broad to have a clear answer, and for this reason it is not a good fit for this site anyway.  Questions should be specific enough so that they can be reasonable answered in a page or so.  The most basic thing you can do is look at the [CUDALink documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/guide/CUDALink.html) which lists a number of operations pre-implemented to be sped up using CUDA, such as `CUDADot`, `CUDATotal`, etc. You can try to use these.

Comment: Take a look at the [CUDALink tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Overview.html), and make sure you also look at the section on memory. This shows how to pre-load arrays onto the GPU so every call to CUDA-accelerated Mathematica functions won't incur the data-transfer overhead.  To do more than what's in the tutorial, you need to resort to writing "kernels" in C to take advantage of CUDA from within Mathematica.

Comment: Let me try to put this in a way that will be more useful to you to decide how to proceed speeding up your program:  whether CUDA will help depends on what your program does precisely.  Unfortunately in most cases it either won't help or it will take a significant amount of work to make use of it.  What you *can* do relatively quickly is to replace certain Mathematica functions with their [CUDA-accelerated equivalents](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/guide/CUDALink.html), when available. This will only give a speedup for large arrays, otherwise it slows things down.

Comment: Would you mind explaining, whether it is possible to rewrite a three dimensional integration job as a form of NIntegrate Library Function in Mathematica, which consists of arrays and some loops; in form of Cuda? What may the prerequisites be? I may add that I have parallelized that procedure without any output errors, but, facing a heavy time consuming calculation job.