# Color points in list plot based on whether they satisfy an equation

Tags: plotting

I wanted to create a set of points (a,b) such that a, b are both integers between -6 and 6. Then I want to color all points (a,b) that satisfy $|a-b|\ge2$ red, and all the remaining points blue. I tried:

```
A = Table[{a, b}, {a, -6, 6}, {b, -6, 6}];
ListPlot[A,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[Abs[x - y] >= 2, Red, Blue]]]
```

But that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `ColorFunction` requires your data set to be joined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = Flatten[
   Table[Style[{a, b}, If[Abs[a - b] >= 2, Red, Blue]], {a, -6, 
     6}, {b, -6, 6}], 1];
ListPlot[A]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, styling before plotting. Nice idea.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is `BubbleChart`

```
BubbleChart[
 Table[{a, b, 1}, {a, -6, 6}, {b, -6, 6}],
 ColorFunction -> Function[{a, b}, If[Abs[a - b] >= 2, Red, Blue]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives methods for you to use have been posted but the reason your attempt fails is that `ColorFunction` requires your data to be joined. e.g

[image]

versus:

[image]

Comment: Cool. I appreciate these kinds of explanations. I didn't get the diagonal lines though, as mine were all vertical. I also added this at the end, `/.Line->Point` and got the points back.

Comment: @David I flattened your data to the next level

Answer (score 2):

You can style the points before you plot (Zviovich's solution) or when you plot (see below).

```
A = Table[{a, b}, {a, -6, 6}, {b, -6, 6}];
ListPlot[MapAt[
   Style[#, If[Abs[First@# - Last@#] >= 2, Red, Blue]] &, {All, All}]@A]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use an empty Plot to generate all your axes and then overlay all your colored points.

```
Show[
  Plot[0, {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> {{-6.5, 6.5}, {-6.5, 6.5}}],
  Graphics[Table[{If[Abs[a-b]>=2, Red, Blue], Point[{a,b}]}, {a,-6,6},{b,-6,6}]]
]
```

[image: points]

Comment: Why not just `Graphics[Table[{If[Abs[a - b] >= 2, Red, Blue], 
   Point[{a, b}]}, {a, -6, 6}, {b, -6, 6}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-6.5, 6.5}, {-6.5, 6.5}}, Axes -> True]`???

Comment: @Mike Honeychurch Some languages have one clear way of writing almost anything. Someone wrote "In Mathematica there are at least a dozen different ways of writing anything, at least three of which are completely incomprehensible." It doesn't seem clear that there is a significant difference in the top half dozen ways of writing something in Mathematica, other than culture and style preference.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways.  I will set them up to be applied to a flat list of points.  The OP's points in `A` can be put in this form by

```
pts = Flatten[A, 1]
```

or more directly constructed with

```
pts = Tuples[Range[-6, 6], 2]
```

#### Separate into two data sets

Use [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) with a functional version of the condition.  Note that the order returned by `GatherBy` is not guaranteed, so some inspection is needed to see which list in `data` is the red set of points. (The order is not random but depends on `pts`; however, I am presenting code that does not rely on knowledge of the internal ordering of `pts`.)

```
cond[{x_, y_}] := Abs[x - y] >= 2;
data = GatherBy[pts, cond];
style = If[cond@data[[1, 1]], {Red, Blue}, {Blue, Red}];
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> style]
```

#### High efficiency

The above is pretty efficient, and `ListPlot` has the [`MaxPlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html) option for downsampling large sets of points. But if you want to deal with all points, a vectorized approach should help.  We have to do the standard trick of translating the inequality into terms of  [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) (c.f. point 2.3 of [Performance tuning in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351)).

```
pts = Tuples[Range[-6, 6], 2];
colfn = Compile[{{i, _Integer, 1}}, {{1., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1}}[[i]]];
col = colfn[1 + (UnitStep[Abs[#1 - #2] - 2] & @@ Transpose[pts])];
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[pts, VertexColors -> col]}, 
 FilterRules[Options[ListPlot], Options[Graphics]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that in V10 (at least in 10.3), we don't have to filter `Options[ListPlot]` for `Graphics`; we may pass `Options[ListPlot]` directly and it is taken care of for us.

To give an idea how to start translating an inequality into terms of `UnitStep`, here is an color function generator for a simple (single) inequality:

```
Clear[x, y, makeColFn];
(*
  ineq : single, simple inequality in terms of x, y;
  colors : {False color, True color}
*)
makeColFn[ineq : (Less | LessEqual | Greater | GreaterEqual)[_, _], colors_] :=
  Compile @@ Block[{Part, pts},
    With[{parts = Replace[ineq,
         {Less[l_, r_] :> 2 - UnitStep[l - r],
          LessEqual[l_, r_] :> 1 + UnitStep[r - l],
          GreaterEqual[l_, r_] :> 1 + UnitStep[l - r],
          Greater[l_, r_] :> 2 - UnitStep[r - l]}
         ] /. {x -> pts[[All, 1]], y -> pts[[All, 2]]},
      colorvec = N@colors /. RGBColor -> List},
     Hold[{{pts, _Real, 2}}, colorvec[[parts]]]
     ]
    ];
```

Note that `1` had to be added to the usual `0/1` output in order to get valid `Part` numbers.  Normally, one deals with `0/1` expressions, for example `1 - UnitStep[l - r]` instead of `2 - UnitStep[l - r]`. For such expressions, complicated combinations of inequalities can be handled using multiplication for `And` and addition (perhaps in combination with `Unitize`) for `Or`; sometimes ingenuity can help, too. :)

Example (medium-sized data):

```
pts = RandomReal[{-6, 6}, {10000, 2}];
col = makeColFn[Abs[x - y] >= 2, {Blue, Red}][pts];
Graphics[{Point[pts, VertexColors -> col]},
 FilterRules[Options[ListPlot], Options[Graphics]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Using `RegionMember` functionality:

Flatten the points:

```
pts = Flatten[#, 1] &@A;
```

Separate points according to region membership:

```
ptsIn = Select[pts, 
   RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[Abs[x - y] >= 2, {x, y}], #] &];
ptsOut = Complement[pts, ptsIn];
```

Plot:

```
ListPlot[{ptsIn, ptsOut}
 , PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], Red], 
   Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], Blue]
   }
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]