# How to estimate the running time of a programme on mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I am solving a system of 6 linear equations containing six unknowns using mathematica. It is taking too much time and still running after 3 hours. can I estimate the approximate running time? Is there any method to minimize the running time of a programme?

Comment: Show us the equations. There is no general possible solution on runtime estimates without the actual code and equations.

Comment: What's wrong with Timing ? Wrap all your code in a single Module if need be and run Timing on it.

Comment: @TradDog It measures, not estimates.

Comment: @Kuba I've heard of many experimental physicists who never knew the difference .)

Answer (score 4):

If your program is already running, there is no way to estimate when it will finish.

If you need to estimate the running time for a function which takes inputs of different sizes, start with small inputs for which the function finishes fast.  Measure the time using `Timing`/`AbsoluteTiming`.  Increase the size of the input, measure the time again.  Obtain a few data points this way.  Try to guess the [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of the algorithm form the result and extrapolate to larger inputs.

How to minimize the running time of a program?  This is answered here in great detail:

- [Performance tuning in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica)