# Delete sublists exceeding certain length

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Given a list like

```
list={{1},{2,3},{3,4,6},{6,7,8,5}};
```

I would like to very efficiently delete all sublists that are longer than a specific length, i.e.:

```
delLongSublists[list,2]
```

> `{{1},{2,3}}`

My attempt at writing this function is:

```
delLongSublists[in_,q_]:=DeleteCases[in, Length[_List] > q, 1]
```

Unfortunately this does not work at all

```
delLongSublists[list, 2]
```

> `{{1},{2,3},{3,4,6},{6,7,8,5}}`

Any suggestion on how to write this function computationally efficiently?

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, x_ /; Length[x] > q]`

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. You should post this as an answer and I will upvote and accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sure there are many ways to do this in Mathematica. one way could be

```
del[in_List, (q_Integer)?Positive]:=DeleteCases[in, x_ /; Length[x] > q];
list = {{1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 6}, {6, 7, 8, 5}};
del[list, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way, using `Pick`.

```
del2[in_List, (q_Integer)?Positive] := Pick[in, (Length[#] <= q & /@ in)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

This is as fast as I can do:

```
delLong[list_, length_] := Pick[list, UnitStep[Length /@ list - (1 + length)], 0]

delLong[{{1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 6}, {6, 7, 8, 5}}, 2]
(*  {{1}, {2, 3}}  *)
```

Big example, with check and timing analysis:

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = Table[RandomInteger[1, RandomInteger[5]], {10000}];

listlengths = Length /@ list;
Accumulate[Last /@ Sort@Tally@listlengths]
Table[Length@delLong[list, n], {n, 0, 5}]
(*
  {1707, 3385, 4960, 6645, 8351, 10000}
  {1707, 3385, 4960, 6645, 8351, 10000}
*)

Table[delLong[list, n], {n, 6}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.012, Null}  *)

Table[Length /@ list, {n, 6}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.012, Null}  *)
```

It's hard to see how it could be done faster than `Length /@ list`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the `Accumulate` is doing. But the last two commands show that deleting the long sublists using your `delLong` effectively takes a much time as just counting the length of all sublists? That sounds pretty fast, since the extra operations seem to produce no overhead.

Comment: @Kagaratsch The sorted tally tells how many lists there are of lengths 0, 1, 2, etc.  `Accumulate` adds them up, so that, say, the third entry in the output indicates how many lists have length 0, 1, or 2.  That's just a check to compare with the output of `delLong` -- Yes, after counting the lengths of the sublists, remaining computation is at least an order of magnitude faster.  See ["vectorized", sects. 1.3 & 2.3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/4999).

Comment: I wonder if it's worth packing the array given by `Length /@ list`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I observed no significant difference for lists up to length 10^6.

Answer (score 4):

Just another way:

```
del[lst_, t_] := Pick[lst, Length@# <= t & /@ lst]
```

e.g.

```
del[list, #] & /@ Range[4]
```

yields:

> {{{1}}, {{1}, {2, 3}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 
>   6}, {6, 7, 8, 5}}}

Comment: oh, I added Pick also and just saw your answer using Pick. I do not know which is faster though. Did not time them. Normally Pick is supposed to be fast.

Comment: @Nasser I have not tested and am not sure how large collection is targetted. May not make any meaningful difference for small size. As you commented 'many ways to do this'...the joy of Mathematica:)

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

```
del[lst_, t_] := Select[lst, Length @ #  <= t &]
```