# Compilation without MainEvaluate

Tags: compile

I'm trying to avoid MainEvaluate in CompiledFunction. I've tried below but I couldn't get rid of it. I'd appreciate any help!!

Here f1 and f2 will be rank 1 list with real type.

```
decision[f1_, f2_] := And @@ Thread[LessEqual[f1, f2]] && Or @@ Thread[Less[f1, f2]];

dominates = Compile[{{f1, _Real, 1}, {f2, _Real, 1}}, 
decision[f1, f2], {{decision[_, _], True | False}}, 
CompilationOptions ->{"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[dominates]
```

Comment: The expression in `decision[]` is not compilable.  Try rewriting it using `UnitStep[]`.

Comment: So you want all the elements of `f1` less than or equal to the corresponding element of `f2` and at least one the pairs unequal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
dominates = Compile[{{f1, _Real, 1}, {f2, _Real, 1}}, 
  Length[Cases[UnitStep[f2 - f1], 0, 1]] == 0 && 
   Length[Cases[Unitize[f2 - f1], 1, 1]] > 0
  ]
```

For further discussion, see para. 2.3 of this answer: [Performance tuning in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351)