# Combination of lists elementwise

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
x = Range[1, 10, 1]
y = Range[2, 10, 2]
```

How can I produce a list consisting of the following elements (first element is the x value, second element the y value and third element some combination of it e.g. here the sum):

```
{
{x[[1]], y[[1]], x[[1]] + y[[1]]},
...
{x[[1]], y[[5]], x[[1]] + y[[5]]},
...
...
...
{x[[10]], y[[1]], x[[10]] + y[[1]]},
...
{x[[10]], y[[5]], x[[10]] + y[[5]]}
}

=

{
{1,2,3},
...
{1,10,11},
...
...
...
{10,2,12},
...
{10,10,20}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `Table` and may be `Flatten` afterwards

Comment: Is this the only possibility?

Comment: No, you can also create first an empty list and fill it with `AppendTo` within a `Do` loop. Try it out :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A more Mathematica-ish/functional approach than `Do` is as follows:

```
x = Range[1, 10, 1];
y = Range[2, 10, 2];
Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2, #1 + #2} &, x, y], 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Matrix multiplication is another option:

```
Tuples[{x, y}].{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
```

Answer (score 4):

As in the comments remarked, you can use `Table` as follows

```
x = Range[1, 10, 1];
y = Range[2, 10, 2];
t1 = Flatten[
  Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], x[[i]] + y[[j]]}, {i, Length@x}, {j, Length@y}]
  ,1]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 6, 7}, {1, 8, 9}, {1, 10, 11}, {2, 2,
>   4}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 6, 8}, {2, 8, 10}, {2, 10, 12}, {3, 2, 5}, {3, 4,
>   7}, {3, 6, 9}, {3, 8, 11}, {3, 10, 13}, {4, 2, 6}, {4, 4, 8}, {4,
>   6, 10}, {4, 8, 12}, {4, 10, 14}, {5, 2, 7}, {5, 4, 9}, {5, 6,    11},
>   {5, 8, 13}, {5, 10, 15}, {6, 2, 8}, {6, 4, 10}, {6, 6, 12}, {6,    8,
>   14}, {6, 10, 16}, {7, 2, 9}, {7, 4, 11}, {7, 6, 13}, {7, 8,    15},
>   {7, 10, 17}, {8, 2, 10}, {8, 4, 12}, {8, 6, 14}, {8, 8,    16}, {8,
>   10, 18}, {9, 2, 11}, {9, 4, 13}, {9, 6, 15}, {9, 8,    17}, {9, 10,
>   19}, {10, 2, 12}, {10, 4, 14}, {10, 6, 16}, {10, 8,    18}, {10, 10,
>   20}}

or, for example, a `Do` loop

```
t2 = {};
Do[
 AppendTo[t2, {x[[i]], y[[j]], x[[i]] + y[[j]]}]
 , {i, Length@x}
 , {j, Length@y}
 ]
t2 == t1
```

> True

There are surely a lot of possibilities to do this.

Comment: Thank you. Is instead of using loops also a solution with `Map` or `ReplaceList` possible?

Comment: [performance tunning: point 3.2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/5478)

Comment: Cool info! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
{##, Plus@##} & @@@ Tuples[{x, y}]
```

Or

```
Distribute[{x, y}, List, List, List, {##, Plus@##} &]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]