# Mathematica taking forever to compute

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I want to simulate the fresnel diffraction through circular aperture.But mathematica is taking forever to calculate.Here is my code.

```
  f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(\[Zeta]*(Exp[
       I*20000 ((d^2 + \[Zeta]^2)^(0.5) + ((p^2 + (x - \[Zeta]*
                  Cos[t])^2 + (y - \[Zeta]*
                  Sin[t])^2)^(0.5)))]))/(d^2 + \[Zeta]^2)^(0.5), {\
\[Zeta], 0, 0.008}]
w[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[f[x, y, d, p, t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
g[x_, y_, d_, p_] := (Abs[w[x, y, d, p]])^2
Plot3D[g[x, y, 0.004, 20], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

What's the way out?
*Specs:i5 7th gen intel processor,12 gb ram

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's compile the integrand into a `Listable` `CompiledFunction`:

```
cintegrand = Block[{x, y, d, p, ζ, t},
   With[{code = 
      N[(ζ (Exp[I 20000 ((d^2 + ζ^2)^(1/2) + ((p^2 + (x - ζ Cos[t])^2 + (y - ζ Sin[t])^2)^(1/2)))]))/(d^2 + ζ^2)^(1/2)]
     },
    Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {d, _Real}, {p, _Real}, {ζ, _Real}, {t, _Real}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Next, pick a Gauss quadrature rule for high order polynomials (the integrand is very smooth but quite oscillatory):

```
{pts, weights, errweights} = NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[9, $MachinePrecision];
```

Divide the integration domain into $m \times n$ rectangles and set up the quadrature points and weights:

```
m = 20;
n = 20;
ζdata = Partition[Subdivide[0., 0.008, m], 2, 1];
tdata = Partition[Subdivide[0., 2 Pi, n], 2, 1];
{ζ, t} = Transpose[Tuples[{Flatten[ζdata.{1. - pts, pts}], Flatten[tdata.{1. - pts, pts}]}]];
ω = Flatten[KroneckerProduct[
    Flatten[KroneckerProduct[Differences /@ ζdata, weights]],
    Flatten[KroneckerProduct[Differences /@ tdata, weights]]
    ]];
```

Define the mapping that parameterizes the graph of OP's function `w`:

```
W = {x, y} \[Function] {x, y, Abs[cintegrand[x, y, 0.004, 20., ζ, t].ω]^2};
```

Compute the values of `W` on a $101 \times 101$ grid:

```
R = 2.;
data = Outer[W, Subdivide[-R, R, 100], Subdivide[-R, R, 100]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 28.2668

Plot the result

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1], PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "w"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please recomend a source for learning such techniques for reducing time of computation,like the use of block,listablecompiledfunction etc..?

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/38178) is a good start. The rest is basically experience, some basics in numerical Mathematics and computer science, reading a lot on StackExchange,... and experience of course.

Comment: Oh, and I would not call `Block` a way of reducing computational time. It is just a scoping construct that works a bit more predictably in conjunction with `Compile` than `Module`. In general, I would advise `Module`.

Answer (score 3):

**TIP**: In Mathematica use **exact** values,because have **infinty** precision.

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[(ζ*(Exp[I*20000 ((d^2 + ζ^2)^(1/2) + ((p^2 + (x - ζ*Cos[t])^2 + 
(y - ζ*Sin[t])^2)^(1/2)))]))/(d^2 + ζ^2)^(1/2), {ζ, 0, 8/1000}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];

g[x_, y_, d_, p_] := Abs[f[x, y, d, p]]^2;

n = 1/6; (*The smaller the value , 3D plot is smoother,but CPU time will increase !!! *)

ListPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[Table[{x, y, g[x, y, 4/1000, 20]},
{x, -2, 2, n}, {y, -2, 2, n}]], 3]]
(*In Range: -2<x<2 and -2<y<2.If you increase range domain CPU time will increase !!! *)
```

[image]

On my a `100$`old laptop calculation time is about `24` minutes.