# How to increase performance of this code for plotting a contour plot?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I have an equation which I need to triple integrate over a unit cube. The equation is

```
pot = NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 + (z - l)^2], {h,-1,1}, {k,-1, 
1},{l,-1,1}];
```

As soon as I enter Shift+Enter it immediately processes the command. But now what I want is to plot its ContourPlot for different ${z}$ values (I chose $z=0.5$). So I give the command

```
ContourPlot[pot /. {z -> 0.5}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

But this piece of code takes just forever to process. I just keep on waiting and waiting but processing never ends (it takes really really long time). I am not sure that how is this such a computationally heavy task. For $z$ other than $0$ it takes longer time.

Is there something that I am doing wrong? I don't think this is a drawback of the device I am using. Is there a way to improve the performance of this code I am using?

P.S. It's been more than 10 minutes but the code for $z=0.5$ has not processed.

For your reference, I am attaching the contour plot for $z=0$.

[image]

This is the output for $z=0.5$ from the code above (it took about 10 minutes)

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173253/mathematica-taking-forever-to-compute/173259#173259. Try user `Henrik Schumacher` answer. You must only to modify the code.

Comment: The problem with these integrals is that they are singular and three-dimensional. That makes it quite expensive. Unfortunately, one also cannot exploit symmetry (e.g. by polar coordinates) in an obvious way...

Comment: But even Vector3D plots are taking such a long time that I could not output them. I did the same with other 3 dimensional Integrals but they took at most a few seconds. This one's not.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk it sure may help. Thanks!

Comment: `pot` has no definition of the variables within it, so of course it will never be evaluated for `z = 0.5` (or indeed any other value).

Comment: It did was evaluated for both z=0 and z=0.5 . But it took really long time to to that. 10-15 minutes as I remember. The picture is the output for the same code I gave above in description for z=0.  You can run the code if you want, it will give the same output.

Comment: The reason you got the same picture "for different values of $z$" is that `pot` is independent of `z`, so of course you're merely plotting the same function.

Comment: No. I got different outputs for both values. The code really works but is very inefficient. I have added the other output to the description of the problem. pot is not independent of $z$. Look the SquareRoot term has $(z-l)^2$ term. Infact pot is a function of $x$, $y$ and $z$. $pot(x,y,z)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One helpfull rule to get fast integration is, to do analytical integration as much as you can.

```
int1 = Integrate[1/Sqrt[(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 + (z - l)^2], {l, -1, 1}, 
         Assumptions -> -1 <= h <= 1 && -1 <= k <= 1 && x \[Element] Reals &&
                        y \[Element] Reals && z \[Element] Reals]

(* -Log[-z + Sqrt[h^2 + k^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 k y + y^2 + z^2]] - 
    Log[z + Sqrt[h^2 + k^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 k y + y^2 + z^2]] + 
    Log[1 - z + Sqrt[1 + h^2 + k^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 k y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2]] + 
    Log[1 + z + Sqrt[1 + h^2 + k^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 k y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]] *)
```

I do the second integration with the rule based integrator (Rubi) by Albert Rich  (see  http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/   ), because, in contrast to Mathematica, it gives an antiderivative without discontinuities.

```
rint2[x_, y_, z_, h_, k_] = Int[int1, k];
```

Take integration values at borders to get the definite integral.

```
rint2def[x_, y_, z_, h_] = 
     rint2[x, y, z, h, 1] - rint2[x, y, z, h, -1] // 
      Simplify[#, Assumptions -> -1 <= h <= 1 && -1 <= k <= 1 && 
         x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals && z \[Element] Reals] &

(*   -h ArcTan[((-1 + y) (-1 + z))/((h - x) Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2])] + 
x ArcTan[((-1 + y) (-1 + z))/((h - x) Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2])] + 
h ArcTan[((1 + y) (-1 + z))/((h - x) Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2])] - 
x ArcTan[((1 + y) (-1 + z))/((h - x) Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2])] - 
h ArcTan[((1 - y) (1 + z))/((h - x) Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2])] + 
x ArcTan[((1 - y) (1 + z))/((h - x) Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2])] - 
h ArcTan[((1 + y) (1 + z))/((h - x) Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2])] + 
x ArcTan[((1 + y) (1 + z))/((h - x) Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2])] - (-1 + 
z) ArcTanh[(1 - y)/Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2]] - 
y ArcTanh[Sqrt[2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2]/(
1 - z)] - 
ArcTanh[(-1 - y)/Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2]] + 
z ArcTanh[(-1 - y)/Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2]] + 
y ArcTanh[Sqrt[2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2]/(
1 - z)] + 
ArcTanh[(1 - y)/Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]] + 
z ArcTanh[(1 - y)/Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]] - 
y ArcTanh[Sqrt[2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]/(
1 + z)] - 
ArcTanh[(-1 - y)/Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]] - 
z ArcTanh[(-1 - y)/Sqrt[
2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]] + 
y ArcTanh[Sqrt[2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]/(
1 + z)] - Log[-z + Sqrt[1 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 + z^2]] -
Log[-z + Sqrt[1 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 + z^2]] + 
Log[1 - z + Sqrt[2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2]] + 
Log[((1 - z + Sqrt[
   2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 - 2 z + z^2]) (1 + z + Sqrt[
   2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]) (1 + z + Sqrt[
   2 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 + 2 z + z^2]))/((z + Sqrt[
   1 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 + z^2]) (z + Sqrt[
   1 + h^2 - 2 h x + x^2 + 2 y + y^2 + z^2]))]   *)
```

The last integration has to be done numericaly.

```
rint3[x_, y_, z_] := NIntegrate[rint2def[x, y, z, h], {h, -1, 1}]
```

`ContourPlot` now finishes within 21 seconds.

```
ContourPlot[rint3[x, y, 1/2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
             ImageSize -> 400] // Timing
```

[image]

Comment: How much time did it take your system to compute int1?

Comment: It takes 16 seconds.

Comment: Strange that it takes very long for me. I had to break it into pieces that way it was fast. Like you did in rint2def. Any idea why could it be?

Comment: I am working with MMA Version 8.0.  May be it works with other assumptions, which yield the same result  `int1 = Integrate[
   1/Sqrt[(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 + (z - l)^2], {l, -1, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> -1 < h < 1 && -1 < k < 1 && x > 0 && y > 0 && 
     z > 0] // Timing ` .

Comment: I see. I'm on 11.3 and 11.2. It could be the issue here. Algorithms might be redefined.