# Access to the temporary solution in NDSolve with StepMonitor

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, monitoring

I want to step-monitor at each time step of a spatio-temporal NDSolve (using the finite element method) the maximum bending of the function sampled over the curent mesh. For this I first need access to all u[xi,t] over the mesh {xi}.
(Note here that I let NDSolve define the mesh)

```
reg = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
shape = D[0.125 Erf[(x - 0.5)/0.125], x];
op = D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - D[u[t, x], {t, 2}];
ics = {u[0, x] == shape, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, ics}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x} ∈ reg, 
      StepMonitor :> Print["xis,uis=" <> ToString["???"]]]
```

1) Is it possible?

2) How to access (from inside NDSolve) the mesh that has been created?

3) How to access the ui's function at each timestep (replacement of "???")?

Thank you for your help.

Denis

Comment: Try `sol["ElementMesh"]`. For 3) I suggest that you take a look at `NDSolveValue` documentation for option `StepMonitor `.

Comment: Thanks Pinti, but question 2 is  "How to access (from inside NDSolve) the mesh that has been created? And for question 3, it is not in the doc.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I misread 2). Then you can create mesh upfront with `ToElementMesh[Line[{{0}, {1}}]]` and pass that to `NDSolveValue`. For 3) you can try something like `StepMonitor :> Print["t=", t, " u=", u[t, x]]`.

Comment: I have already tried with u[t, 0] because x is nothing, whereas t is the current time at each timestep. But I don't know why, even u is not known from inside NDSolve for this spatio-temporal case...

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how to get the mesh out of `NDSolve` but you can use the subprocesses described in [Components and Data Structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) to reimplement `NDSolve` with a hook to the element mesh.  Note that below is the idea of an implementation that works on the OP's example.  I'm not sure what will happen if it is tried on a problem in which there is no FEM `ElementMesh` created.

```
ndsolve`mesh;  (* hook for access to ElementMesh *)
ndsolve[stuff___] := Module[{state, s},
   state = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[stuff];
   ndsolve`mesh = First[state]["FiniteElementData"]["FEMMethodData"]["ElementMesh"];
   Block[{s = #},
      NDSolve`Iterate[s, NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[s@"VariableRanges", "T"]];
      NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[s]
      ] & /@ state
   ];

foo = {};
ndsolve[{op == 0, ics}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x} ∈ reg,
 StepMonitor :> (foo = {foo, 
     Plot[Evaluate@ElementMeshInterpolation[{ndsolve`mesh}, u[t, x]][x2],
      {x2} ∈ reg, PlotRange -> {-0.02, 1.3}, 
      PlotLabel -> Row[{HoldForm[t], " = ", t}]]})]

ListAnimate@Flatten[foo]
```

[image]

The use of linked lists to accumulate results (in `foo` above) and its efficiency is discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351)
and
[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/4999).

Comment: Brillant!!! Thank you!

Comment: @user3650925 You're welcome.  Note I didn't put any checking that each of the three major `NDSolve` steps were successful.  If one fails, then expect any succeeding step to fail miserably.