# How to use AppendTo in a While loop?

Tags: procedural-programming

I am trying to code a while loop that uses `AppendTo` to append the loop variable to an empty list.

```
even = {}
i = 1; While[i <= 5, Print[i]; AppendTo[even, i]; i++]
```

This code does not give any output. Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The code is not intended to give an output. It alters the symbol `even` five times, then even contains the (desired?) output - all numbers, not only the even ones.

Comment: It should be noted that the AppendTo function isn't ideal for loops. The documentation explains in more detail.

Comment: Can you explain why you expect this piece of code to return a value (an output) at all? `While` does not return anything. If it did, what would be a reasonable thing for it to return?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
even = {} ; 
i = 1; 
While[i <= 5, Print[i];If[EvenQ[i], AppendTo[even, i]]; i++]

even
(*{2, 4}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html)/[`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) is more appropriate than [`AppendTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html) in the context of step-by-step list building: the latter takes longer as your list gets longer, whereas the former keeps up its speed until the end.

```
i = 1;
even = Reap[While[i <= 5, Print[i]; Sow[i]; i++]][[2, 1]]
(*    1    *)
(*    2    *)
(*    3    *)
(*    4    *)
(*    5    *)
(*    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}    *)
```

Of course, this is only useful if you do something more complex in the loop. For this particular case, [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) is even better, [as user2757771 points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202600/26598).

Answer (score 4):

The standard Table function also supports multi-line inputs, the last line will be used to create the table

```
Table[Print[i]; i, {i, 5}]
```

The output would look like this:

```
even = Table[Print[i]; i, {i, 5}]

1
2
3
4
5
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

But the value stored for `even` is just:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 4):

Linked lists (see [Performance tuning in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351)) are another, efficient alternative.

```
even = {}
i = 1; While[i <= 5, even = {even, i}; i++]

Flatten[even]

(*  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }  *)
```

(I don't know why people use `Print[]` except for debugging.  I suppose it's a C thing.  To monitor progress, you can use `Monitor[]` or my current favorite, `PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock[Infinity], i}`.  To output data, there are better ways than `Print[]`.)

Answer (score 3):

Just to go overkill on Michael E2's point that `Print` is pretty much useless except in a debug environment, here's a little automated `Monitor`:

```
monitored~SetAttributes~HoldAll;
monitored[
  monitoredVars : {__Symbol} | Automatic : Automatic,
  expr_,
  ignoredContexts : StringPattern`StringPatternQ : "System`"
  ] :=
 Replace[
  If[Hold[monitoredVars] === Hold[Automatic],
   Thread[
    DeleteDuplicates@
     Cases[Hold[expr], 
      s_Symbol?(Function[Null, ! StringMatchQ[Context[#], ignoredContexts], 
          HoldFirst]) :>
       Hold[s],
      Infinity
      ],
    Hold
    ],
   Hold[monitoredVars]
   ],
  Hold[mvars_] :>
   (
    PrintTemporary@
     Internal`LoadingPanel@Dynamic[
      Grid[
       {
        {"Time:", NumberForm[Quantity[Clock[Infinity], "Seconds"], 3]},
        {"Vars:", 
         Grid[
          {Row@{Extract[#, 1, Defer], ":"}, ReleaseHold[#]} & /@ 
           Thread[Hold[mvars]],
          Alignment -> {Left, Top}
          ]
         }
        },
       Alignment -> Left
       ]
      ];
    expr
    )
  ]
```

Then we can watch what happens (the `Pause` is just there to be able to see it happen):

```
monitored[
 even = {};
 n = 50;
 i = 1; While[i <= n, Pause[.1]; even = {even, i}; i++];
 Flatten[even]
 ]

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, \
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, \
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50}
```

[image]

We can also just watch `i`:

```
monitored[
 {i},
 even = {};
 n = 25;
 i = 1; While[i <= n, Pause[.1]; even = {even, i}; i++];
 Flatten[even]
 ]

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, \
22, 23, 24, 25}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to Print the list at the end of the While loop, you can do the following

```
Module[{even = List[], i},
 i = 1;
 While[i <= 5, 
  Print["Now appending " <> ToString[i] <> " to the list"]; 
  AppendTo[even, i]; i++];
 even
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, going full functional, and making use of the magic `Nothing` symbol:

```
feven[n_?EvenQ] := n
feven[_] = Nothing;
Map[feven, Range[5]]
(* {2, 4} *)
```

If you **must** see the input, you can look at what `Range[5]` yields.

This kind of approach helps speed things up if the function you're mapping to the input is complicated and expensive. In that case, use `ParallelMap`. Factoring the problem into simple functions you can try out before composing higher level (but still simple) expressions from them also avoids much difficult debugging.