# How to illustrate the optimal solution with kinked constraint?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate, piecewise

I have a simple optimization problem with a linear, continuous constraint or a kinked constraint.  The optimal solution is either a tangent point with f*<T or at the kink with f*=T.  The standard illustration is running fine; the illustration of the kinked constraint too.

*I am struggling to illustrate the optimal solution with conditions in the manipulate output.*

Thank you!

**Update 12/7/2020:** I reduced the code and added an illustration of the problem's objective.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
(* Objective function *)
U[f_, c_, a_] := f^a*c^(1 - a);

(* Downward-slope part of constraint *)
Bconstr[f_, c_, T_, w_] := c - (T - f)*w - n;

(* Kinked Constrained *)
Bconstrtransf[f_, c_, T_, w_, n_] = 
  Piecewise[{{c - (T - f)*w - n, f < T}}];

(* Optimality Conditions *)
MRS = D[U[f, c, a], f]/D[U[f, c, a], c];
AbsSlpCon = D[Bconstr[f, c, T, w], f];
TC = MRS - AbsSlpCon;

(* Optimal Solution  - either tangency for f*<T or f=T *)
sols = Solve[{TC == 0, Bconstrtransf[f, c, T, w, n] == 0}, {f, c}][[1,1, 2]];
fcopttransf[T_, w_, a_, n_, f_] := Evaluate[{f, c} /. Last[sols]];

(* Illustration: Optimal Choice with Kinked Constrained - either on downward (point A) or at kink (point B)*)
c1transf[T_, w_, n_, f_] := 
 c /. Solve[Bconstrtransf[f, c, T, w, n] == 0, c][[1]]
vline[T_, w_, n_] := Line[{{T, 0}, {T, n}}]

c2transf[T_, w_, a_, n_, f_] = 
  Quiet[c /. 
    Solve[U[## & @@ fcopttransf[T, w, a, n, f], a] == U[f, c, a], c][[
     1]]];

Manipulate[
 Plot[{c1transf[T, w, n, f], c2transf[T, w, a, n, f]}, {f, 0, 24}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 6000}}, 
  Epilog -> {ColorData[97][1], vline[T, w, n], Red, PointSize@Large, 
    Point@fcopttransf[T, w, a, n, f]}], {{T, 8}, 1, 24, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{w, 120}, 10, 200, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{n, 500}, 0, 2000, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 0.5}, 10^-2, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**Update 12/13/2020:** The answer and comments below provide a solution in which the constraint of f<T is not binding and the optimal point is outside the constraint.

In the scenario below, the red dot as optimal solution should **not** be outside the constraint but at the kink as the constraint dictates f<=T.  The tangent curve is also not appearing.

The problem works fine without a piecewise constraint and solutions can be calculated and illustrated - both linear c1 and nonlinear c2.

[image]

Comment: Why are there three `Manipulate` commands? The statement of the problem seems much simpler than the code. I think you'd be more likely to get help if you eliminated all but what is necessary.  If the three `Manipulates` are necessary, please explain why and how each is a step in solving the problem.

Comment: I used the first two [manipulates] to illustrate the problem. The added picture of the problem made them redundant. I dropped these two parts. Thanks!

Comment: I have gone back the steps because You mixed up with the rules rather too much. This should be easier to be understood and modified.

Comment: Hi. I did follow Your wish. Please rate.

Comment: I added comments below and updated my initial post highlighting the problems with the proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
(*Illustration:Optimal Choice with Standard Constrained*)
c1[T_, w_, f_] := Solve[Bconstr[f, c, T, w] == 0, c][[1, 1, 2]];
c2[T_, w_, a_, f_] = 
 Quiet[c /. Solve[U[## & @@ fcopt[T, w, a], a] == U[f, c, a], c][[1]]];
Manipulate[
 Plot[{c1[T, w, f], c2[T, w, a, f]}, {f, 0, 24}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 6000}}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Large, Point@fcopt[T, w, a]}], {{T, 8}, 1,
   24, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{w, 120}, 10, 200, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 0.5}, 10^-2, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

works properly.

(*Illustration:Kinked Constrained*)

```
c1transf[T_, w_, n_] := 
 Solve[Bconstrtransf[f, c, T, w, n] == 0, c][[1, 1, 2]]
vline[T_, w_, n_] := Line[{{T, 0}, {T, n}}]
(*Illustration:Kinked Constrained*)

c1transf[T_, w_, n_, f_] := 
 c /. Solve[Bconstrtransf[f, c, T, w, n] == 0, c][[1]]
vline[T_, w_, n_] := Line[{{T, 0}, {T, n}}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[c1transf[T, w, n, f], {f, 0, 24}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 6000}}, 
  Epilog -> {ColorData[97][1], vline[T, w, n]}], {{T, 8}, 1, 24, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{w, 120}, 10, 200, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{n, 500}, 0, 2000, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

works properly.

```
(*Optimal Choice:Kinked Constrained-either tangency for f*<T or f* =T*)

sols2 = Solve[{TC == 0, Bconstrtransf[f, c, T, w, n] == 0}, {f, 
     c}][[1, 1, 2]];
fcopttransf[T_, w_, a_, n_, f_] := Evaluate[{f, c} /. Last[sols2]];

(*Illustration:Optimal Choice with Kinked Constrained*)

c2transf[T_, w_, a_, n_, f_] = 
  Quiet[c /. 
    Solve[U[## & @@ fcopttransf[T, w, a, n, f], a] == U[f, c, a], 
      c][[1]]];
```

The last Manipulate is really complex. It complains about solutions in this form

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{c1transf[T, w, n, f], c2transf[T, w, a, n, f]}, {f, 0, 24}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 6000}}, 
  Epilog -> {ColorData[97][1], vline[T, w, n], Red, PointSize@Large, 
    Point@fcopttransf[T, w, a, n, f]}], {{T, 8}, 1, 24, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{w, 120}, 10, 200, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{n, 500}, 0, 2000, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 0.5}, 10^-2, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

That repairs the misconceptions on the level of variables, parameters. I replaced rules by the corresponding part. For last manipulate this is an improvement. I did not prefer to correct the implemented logic and semantics. It is now in the `c2transf` function that problems occur. I am the opinion the question "I am struggling to illustrate the optimal solution with conditions in the manipulate output." is done by that effort.

I suggest to make use of ideas from this demonstration: [PhysicsOfASlidingLadder](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PhysicsOfASlidingLadder/).

I shortened it so that it works:
(*Optimal Solution-either tangency for f*<T or f=T*)

fcopttransf[T_, w_, a_, n_, f_] :=
Solve[a c - w*((1 - a) f) == 0 && c - (T - f)*w - n == 0, {f, c}][[1,
All, 2]]

(*Illustration:Optimal Choice with Kinked Constrained-either on 

downward (point A) or at kink (point B)*)

c1transf[T_, w_, n_, f_] := n - f w + T w
vline[T_, w_, n_] := Line[{{T, 0}, {T, n}}]

c2transf[T_, w_, a_, n_, f_] =
Quiet[Solve[(-1)^a (1/w)^(1 - a) == f^a*c^(1 - a) && f < T && f < T,
c][[1, 1, 2]]];

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{c1transf[T, w, n, f], c2transf[T, w, a, n, f]}, {f, 0, T}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 6000}}, 
  Epilog -> {ColorData[97][1], vline[T, w, n], Red, PointSize@Large, 
    Point@fcopttransf[T, w, a, n, f]}], {{T, 8}, 1, 24, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{w, 120}, 10, 200, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{n, 500}, 0, 2000, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 0.5}, 10^-2, 1, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Animation of what is possible]

The trick is given in this post by [@leonid-shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin): [performance tuning in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica#4721352): "Avoid full Mathematica symbolic evaluation process as much as possible.". [@leonid-shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) points out that even compiled functions of Your type may bail out into being not fast and keep causing trouble.

```
With[{T = 20, w = 5, n = 2, c = 1, f = 2}, 
 Plot[{Re[(-1)^a (1/w)^(1 - a)], f^a*c^(1 - a), 
   c2transf[T, w, a, n, f]}, {a, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image: go]

There are only single points where a solution exists:

```
Plot[{Re[(-1)^a (1/5)^(1 - a)], .1^a*1^(1 - a), 
  c2transf[20, 5, a, 2, 2]}, {a, 0, 2.6}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: example for multiple points in a parameter sets]

Based on the number of parameters this can only be solved to examples. This already makes use of the Mathematica definition of `Re`.

Have fun.

OK. I see I have to change the syntactics.

This is not so a nice problem to be solves with `FindRoot`. Graphical is much more appropriate to gain understanding and routine. How to built this last part.

Do try to understand this code:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{PointSize[Large], 
    Point[{f1, (A ((f1 - c1)^-a))^(1/1 - a)}], 
    Point[{f2, (B ((f2 - c2)^-b))^(1/1 - b)}], {Dashed, 
     Line[{{f2, 0}, {f2, (B ((f2 - c2)^-b))^(1/1 - b)}}], 
     Line[{{f1, 0}, {f1, (A ((f1 - c1)^-a))^(1/1 - a)}}], 
     Line[{{0, (B ((f2 - c2)^-b))^(1/1 - 
           b)}, {f2, (B ((f2 - c2)^-b))^(1/1 - b)}}], 
     Line[{{0, (A ((f1 - c1)^-a))^(1/1 - 
           a)}, {f1, (A ((f1 - c1)^-a))^(1/1 - a)}}]}, 
    Arrow[{{S, 0}, {TT, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, U}, {0, V}}], 
    Inset["c", {-0.2, (B ((f2 - c2)^-b))^(1/1 - b)}], 
    Inset["c*", {-0.2, (A ((f1 - c1)^-a))^(1/1 - a)}], 
    Inset["f2", {f2, -0.2}], Inset["f1", {f1, -0.2}], 
    Inset["f", {TT, -0.2}], Inset["c", {-0.2, V}]}], 
  Plot[{Labeled[(A ((f - c1)^-a))^(1/1 - a), A f^a], 
    Labeled[(B ((f - c2)^-b))^(1/1 - b), B f^b], 
    Piecewise[{{(B ((f2 - c2)^-b))^(1/1 - b) + (f - f2) (-1 + 
           b) b B f2^(-1 - b) (c2 + B f2^-b)^-b, f < f1}, {0, 
       f == f1}, {Nothing, f > f1}}]}, {f, S, TT}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
   PlotRange -> {{S, TT}, {U, V}}, AxesLabel -> {f, c}, Ticks -> tcks,
    Epilog -> {}]], {{a, 0.5}, 0.01, 1 - 0.00001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 0.6}, 0.01, 1 - 0.000001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{A, 1.47}, 0.1, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{B, 1}, 0.1, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c1, 0.1}, 0.1, 1.5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c2, 0.2}, 0.1, 1.6, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{S, 0.0001}, 0.000001, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{TT, 6}, 0.1, 7, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{U, 0.01}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{V, 5}, 0.1, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f1, 0.6}, 0.01, 3, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f2, 0.4}, 0.01, 3, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

The code is for exploration and learning purposes only. It offers nevertheless a graphical full fledged Mathematica `Manipulate` for solving the problem displayed in the questions picture.

Would I attempt to solve this with a `FindRoot` it would fail. The final problem would be

```
Solve[(B (f2^-b) + c2)^(1/1 - b) + (f - f2) (-1 + b) b B f2^(-1 - 
     b) (c2 + B f2^-b)^-b == (A ((f - c1)^-a))^(1/1 - a), f]
```

or `FindRoot`, `Reduce` or else Mathematica solving built-in. The problem can be tackled with more effort. It is necessary to transfer the constrains from the introductory `Manipulate` into the built-in selected finally for determining a solution. That is again in the range of the effort done for the `Manipulate`.

This is long and tedious. This does not avoid possible  singularities, domains. It is a start that works. It requires to set up an own strategy how to reach an point induced by the picture of the question. It requires to name the parameters. There is still some difference to the pictures. But it is much further develop then the code from the original question.

It avoids complete what the solution of the question with the code targeted. This is in difference to the original question a problem of the type [Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) or `Power`. It is oriented to isentropic processes from [ideal gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas). It simply adds the linear tangent to the power curve and lets the point to manipulation. This offers insight and demands the effort of gaining experience first.

It confines the problem close to given graphics and gives only some basic idea that can be used to proceed further to the graphics in the manner of a framework for such tasks. It does not confine the ranges at all. It does not avoid singularities of the used inverse functions nor does it solve the problem overall. It is just a graphical approach to solutions in the open experimental fashion that Mathematica `Manipulate` induces.

There many pedagogical questions open. But one should be cleared locality triumph over $FindRoot$ global attempting.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a suggestion regarding alternative logic and semantics to correct the error messages and not ending computation?

Comment: Please give me some ideas on what this is by purpose. What is expected it to show?

Comment: The U-function is the objective function in the constrained maximization problem the other two functions are possible constraints. The one of interest is the second one creating a kink. I want to illustrate the optimal where the objective function is tangent to the kinked constrained. 

I added a picture to my question.

Comment: I want to show how dependent on parameter values the optimal solution looks like "A" (on the downward-sloped part) or "B" (on the kink). Values of f>T are not feasible in this application. The parameter that causes the kink is "n" for n>0.

Comment: Thanks for the update - unfortunately, it's not working: the second graph is missing (c2trasnf) and the constrained not binding. If you move the sliders for "n" or "a" far to the right, then you'll notice that red point is no longer part of the kinked set. It should be restrained to remain at the kink. The constraining condition f<T is not working. Mathematica also doesn't stop running and I have to abort the evaluation.

Comment: There is another curve, but that is not visible because of the given settings of the parameter a. The range of the c2transf is only up to 25 and that is not selected in the given question. Everything works and is fine.

Comment: I updated my question above and added a scenario with parameter values where the constraint is not binding - the optimal solution is illustrated for a range which is outside the constraint. The curve should also appear as illustrated in my sketched graph above. Thanks!