# Functional realisation of do-loop

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, procedural-programming

I'm currently optimising my code and I'm using a lot of loops, so I was wondering if there is a smarter or faster way to do things like:

`Do[If[MemberQ[List1[[II]], List2_], AppendTo[Newlist1, List1[[II]]]], {II, Length[List1]}]`

I guess using `Apply` would be better, but since I'm not primary a programmer I would be happy for any help. Thank you!

Comment: `newlist = Intersection[list1,list2]` would do this. Sorts the elements in the results, though; [see here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection.html). In general it is a good idea to use builtin functions instead of "rolling your own".

Comment: `List2_` should not have `_` after it. That's supposed to be for arguments and patterns. You don't need to use `[[ ]]`. You can write `Do` loops like this for example: `Do[Print[x]; , {x, {"a", "b", "c"}}]` and the x will take the value in the list on each iteration. Finally, don't use `AppendTo`, use `Reap` and `Sow` instead.

Comment: @Hausdorff `AppendTo` is not good, better to use something like `newlist = Select[list1, MemberQ[list2, #] &]`. [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/26598) for a discussion.

Comment: I really like the last one @Roman ,  how would I do that if list1is a product e.g. list1 = {abcd,...,...} and list2={a,r,l,m}. I would like to extract elements of list1 if elements there contain elements of list2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First question: select those elements in `list1` that also appear in `list2`:

```
list1 = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
list2 = {e, g, i};
Select[list1, MemberQ[list2, #] &]
(*    {e}    *)
```

Second question: select those elements in `list1` that have a factor that is in `list2`:

```
list1 = {a b c d, x y z, m n o};
list2 = {a, r, l, m};
Select[list1, IntersectingQ[List @@ #, list2] &]
(*    {a b c d, m n o}    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, first remove from the first list the elements of the second one:

```
lst1 = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
lst2 = {b, c, g};
Complement[lst1, lst2]
(*  {a, d, e, f}  *)
```

and then append it to the newList.

```
Clear[newList];
newList = {AA, BB, CC}; (*This is the initial newList*)
AppendTo[newList, Complement[lst1, lst2]] // Flatten
(*  {AA, BB, CC, a, d, e, f}   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: `Join` might be better than `AppendTo` and `Flatten`.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

```
la = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
lb = {e, g, i};

Cases[la, Alternatives @@ lb]
```

{e}

**Question 2** (see comment)

```
la = {a b c d, x y z, m n o};
lb = {a, r, l, m};

Pick[la, ContainsAny[#, lb] & /@ List @@@ la]
```

{a b c d, m n o}

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

```
la = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
lb = {e, g, i};

DeleteCases[la, Alternatives @@ Union @@ UniqueElements[{la, lb}]]
```

> {e}

**Question 2**

```
la = {a b c d, x y z, m n o};
lb = {a, r, l, m};

DeleteCases[la, x_ /; DisjointQ[List @@ x, lb]]
```

> {a b c d, m n o}