# Calling a function of multiple variables for several values of these variables in an automatic way

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a function of multiple variables such as

```
f[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ,c_?NumericQ]:= a - b + c;
```

and I want to call it mutliple times for different values of `a`,`b` and `c` in this particular manner

```
ps = Range[0.8, 1.2, 0.05];

H1 = Table[f[ps[[kk]],1,1],{kk,1,Length@ps}];
H2 = Table[f[1,ps[[kk]],1],{kk,1,Length@ps}];
H3 = Table[f[1,1,ps[[kk]]],{kk,1,Length@ps}];
```

The first time the function is called, its first variable should take the values of `ps`, while the others take the value `1`. For the second call, the second variable takes the value of `ps`, while the 1st and the 3rd remain ones etc.

Then I manipulate the lists above using `Thread`:

```
data1 = Thread[{ps,H1}];
data2 = Thread[{ps,H2}];
data3 = Thread[{ps,H3}];
```

This is a very simple example I used for demonstration purposes and calling the function manually isn't such a big deal. The function I am working with, however, involves way more variables, should be called liked this just as many times and further list manipulation is required once the results are acquired.

Typing everything manually does not seem like a good coding practice and I would really appreciate if somebody could figure out an automatic way to achieve the same result as laid out above.

Comment: Hi you could maybe define your function to take a vector argument and, defining `length` to be the length of the list that `f` takes as an argument, maybe you can use `RotateRight` on `{ps[[k]],ConstantArray[1,length-1]}`. To test that all the components of the vector are numeric you could use `VectorQ[list, NumericQ]`

Comment: Sorry on `Prepend[ConstantArray[1, 3 - 1], ps[[k]]]` not `{ps[[k]],ConstantArray[1,length-1]}`

Comment: The method depends on how you set up the function. You can also use something like `g[a__?NumericQ] := Total@List@a;` and use something like `g[Sequence @@ RotateRight@Prepend[ConstantArray[1, 3 - 1], ps[[k]]]]`.  You can also maybe consider taking an association as the argument for easier reading and thus maybe easier debugging later on

Comment: For an example of using an association: `gqr[r_] /; VectorQ[Values[r], NumericQ] := r["b"] + 5 - r["w"]`. And then test `gqr[<|"t" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "w" -> 0.4|>]` and `gqr[<|"t" -> 4, "b" -> 8, "w" -> u|>]`

Comment: An association is nice because you can give explicit meaning to the keys using strings rather than integers with lists.

Comment: I am not very familiar with some of the code in your suggestions. I will do some research on it and try it out. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: ok have fun and sorry i made a restiction above it should be `Prepend[ConstantArray[1, length - 1], ps[[k]]]` where length is defined above rather than `Prepend[ConstantArray[1, 3 - 1], ps[[k]]]`.  Note however that repeatedly using `Prepend` on a list can lead to a slower code because mathematica creates a new list each time. That's not the case here there is no nested prepend.

Comment: For more information on the cost of using `Prepend` and `Append`, if you seach for Append via ctrl+F this is mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351) for example but I think there is a more detailed explanation somewhere else