# function definition with a given list of parameters: how to use Evaluate[] properly?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

given a list of variables

```
variables = {a, b, c};
```

I want to automatically define a function

```
f[{a_,b_,c_},x_] := g[a,b,c,x]
```

(I do need a delayed assignment here, since g is a compiled function).

As a first attempt I define

```
f[Evaluate[Pattern[#,Blank[]]&/@variables], x_] := Evaluate[Append[variables, x]]
```

which works out as

```
?f

f[{a_,b_,c_},x_]:={a,b,c,x}
```

This is good so far.

As a next step I want to pass the parameter list to the function g:

```
f[Evaluate[Pattern[#,Blank[]]&/@variables], x_] := g @@ Evaluate[Append[variables, x]]
```

This does not work, as the argument list for g is now left unevaluated:

```
?f

f[{a_,b_,c_},x_]:=g@@Evaluate[Append[variables,x]]
```

What do I need to change in my definition of f in order to get

```
?f

f[{a_,b_,c_},x_]:=g[a,b,c,x]
```

Thanks for any help! Roman

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: something like `f[p : Pattern @@@ Thread[{variables, _}], x_] := g[## & @@ p, x]`?

Comment: Bill, as g is a compiled function, I cannot evaluate the whole RHS.

Answer (score 6):

I think this approach is an overreaction. Maybe something like this will be ok?

```
f[l_, x_] := g[##, x] & @@ l
```

Comment: Kuba, yes, much simpler! Thanks a lot.

Comment: kguler, naming the pattern is a good idea. But in this case I think Kuba's solution is simpler, by avoiding naming of the individual components of the parameter list at all.

Answer (score 4):

While Kuba's answer is simpler, what you asked for can be accomplished also rather easily with the help of the [nested injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21859/81):

```
variables /. {vars__} :> 
    (Map[Pattern[#, Blank[]] &, {vars}] /. {patts__} :>  
         (f[{patts}, x_] := g[vars, x]))
```