# different situations with Compilation of ConstantArray

Tags: matrix, compile

First, we load some tools related to `Compile` for analysis.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
On["CompilerWarnings"];
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True];
```

**0**

```
test0 = Compile[{x}, ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]]
```

will not show message, but

```
test0 // CompilePrint
```

shows there is `MainEvaluate` like this

```
T(R2)1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[ConstantArray][ R0, T(I1)0]]
```

**1**

```
test1 = Compile[{x}, Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]]
```

`test1` actually successfully compiled `ConstantArray`!! Because  `test1//CompilePrint` shows

```
T(R2)0 = {{R0, R0}, {R0, R0}}
```

This is understandable, according to the doc

> You can use Compile[...,Evaluate[expr]] to specify that expr
>   should be evaluated symbolically before compilation.

**2**

Now comes the strangest part

```
test2 = Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]; y]
```

running this directly popup error message

> Compile::noinfo: No information is available for compilation of
>   Evaluate[ConstantArray[x,{2,2}]]. The compiler will use an external
>   evaluation and make assumptions about the return type. >>
>
> Compile::extscalar: Evaluate[ConstantArray[x,{2,2}]] cannot be
>   compiled and will be evaluated externally. The result is assumed to be
>   of type Void. >>

and `test2//CompilePrint` shows

```
V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x, y}, {{x, x}, {x, x}}][ R0, R1]]
```

This is different from `test0`, but it is still a `MainEvaluate`.

**3**

Let us see this

```
test3 = Compile[{x}, Block[{y}, y = Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]]]
test3 // CompilePrint
```

also show error message and

```
1   T(R2)1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[ConstantArray][ R0, T(I1)0]]
2   T(R2)2 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Evaluate][ T(R2)1]]
```

**4**

Since `test1` is full compiled, so we can inline it freely as follows

```
Compile[{x, y}, test1[x]; y, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> 
     True}] // CompilePrint

Compile[{x}, Block[{y}, y = test1[x]], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> 
     True}] // CompilePrint
```

The above two both are fully compiled. Free from `MainEvaluate`.

**This trick also works for `IdentityMatrix`, `DiagonalMatrix`**

**Question:**

1. Why `Compile[...,Evaluate[expr]]` is not working for `ConstantArray`
   for situation 2 and 3 ?
2. Why in 1, there is no error message, while in 2 and 3 there are error message?

Comment: `Evaluate` must wrap the whole argument, it does not work buried inside a CompoundExpression.

Comment: @SimonWoods hi, Simon. What do you mean?

Comment: He means that `Compile[{x,y}, Evaluate[Block[{a}, a=ConstantArray[x, {2,2}]; y; a}]]]`, with `Evaluate` surrounding the whole expression, works. If you need to control evaluation, using `InlineExternalDefinitions` as you show is the way to go. No idea on the error messages.

Comment: @ZachB Thank you, you are right. But this kind of Evaluation of whole block is not useful, since most of the time, we have a lot more code in a block to be compiled, evaluate the whole will spoil the whole thing

Comment: This behavior of `Evaluate` is documented, in [Possible Issues section](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html#333366049) we can read: "`Evaluate` works only on the first level, directly inside a held function". To overcome this, you can use something like following function: `deepEvaluate = Function[, Unevaluated[#] /. HoldPattern[Evaluate][x_] :> RuleCondition[x], HoldFirst];` `Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]; y] // deepEvaluate`.

Comment: @jkuczm Wow, your `deepEvaluate` is extremely useful in `Compile`. Thanks so much for sharing. Would you like to make it an answer and add some explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Why `Compile[...,Evaluate[expr]]` is not working for `ConstantArray` for situation 2 and 3 ?

It doesn't work as you expect because, as already noted in comments, `Evaluate` is to deep inside `Compile` expression.

As we can read in [Possible Issues section](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html#333366049) of `Evaluate` documentation:

> `Evaluate` works only on the first level, directly inside a held function

In `Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]; y]` expression, `Evaluate` is on second level, inside [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) and leads to `MainEvaluate` call in which it's put inside a function: `Function[{x, y}, Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]]`. Since now `Evaluate` is on first level inside `Function`, it evaluates to `Function[{x, y}, {{x, x}, {x, x}}]`.

In `Compile[{x}, Block[{y}, y = Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]]]` expression, `Evaluate` is in level 3 inside `Block` and `Set`.

---

In cases in which you want to evaluate sub-expression on arbitrary level before evaluating whole `Compile` expression, you may use following function.

```
ClearAll[deepEvaluate]
SetAttributes[deepEvaluate, HoldFirst]
deepEvaluate[expr_] := 
   Unevaluated[expr] /. HoldPattern[Evaluate][subExpr_] :> RuleCondition[subExpr]
```

It takes unevaluated `Compile` expression and replaces all sub-expressions wrapped with `Evaluate` with their evaluated forms using undocumented [`RuleCondition`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/14303).
If one wants to stick with documented functions only, then `RuleCondition` can be replaced by [Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29318/14303).

With `deepEvaluate`, `ConstantArray` is evaluated in both compiled functions:

```
Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]; y] // 
  deepEvaluate // CompilePrint
Compile[{x}, Block[{y}, y = Evaluate@ConstantArray[x, {2, 2}]]] // 
  deepEvaluate // CompilePrint
```

they both have `T(R2)0 = {{R0, R0}, {R0, R0}}` in byte code.

For more complicated problems of partial evaluation of held expressions there are also techniques like:
[injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/14303) (also in [nested version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21859/14303)), [code freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746584/5400699), or [step by step evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24596/14303).

---

> 2. Why in 1, there is no error message, while in 2 and 3 there are error message?

As to this question, unfortunately I have no idea.

Comment: accpet your answer,+1.  For `CompoundExpression`, do you mean for `A;B;C`, it is actually `CompoundExpression[A,B,C]`, so A is in 2nd level?

Comment: Yes, look at `Hold[A; B; C] // FullForm`. `A` is in first level of `CompoundExpression`, so in second level of `Hold[A; B; C]`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Actually I tried `FullForm[A;B;C]` and can't see `CompundExpression`. Now I understand.