# How Defer[1+Evaluate[1+1] work?

Tags: programming, expression-construction

I want to generate some expressions.
The expression is not evaluated expect some parts will evaluate first.

A simple example is
`Defer[1+1+1]` and in this expression I need the last puls operation is evaluated.
Some thing like `Defer[1+ Evaluate[1+1]]`.
However this do not work and return `1+Evaluate[1+1]`. The `Evaluate` is shadowed by `Defer`.

How can I get `1+2` as the result.

I will use this method to generate `WhenEvent[ ]` in `NDSolve`.

Comment: `Evaluate` work on the first level of a held expression. Here it is deeper. you can use `With` or something like `Defer[1+#]&[1+1]`

Comment: Maybe you'll find [deepEvaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103293/14303) useful.