# Building conditional lists with Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I'm trying to select elements of a list that satisfy some criteria using `Manipulate[]`.

Given 2 lists:

```
list1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
list2 = {{9, 0}, {2, 1}, {9.5, 3}};
```

I want to build a function that, when some criteria are `True`, will look for them at a specific position in `list2`. Let me show with an example:

Consider the case in which I only want to find if elements in position 1 of `list2` are `>=9` and then take the corresponding position from `list1`. I would write

```
Pick[list1, Map[#[[1]] >= 9 &, list2]]
(*{{a, b, c}, {g, h, i}}*)
```

However, if I was to look into elements in position 1 being `>=9` and elements of position 2 being `<2` I would write

```
Pick[list1, Map[#[[1]] >= 9 && #[[2]] < 2 &, list2]]
(*{{a, b, c}}*)
```

**But what I want is** to have a manipulable function that uses the `And` function in the second case, but without excluding the possibility that only one of the criterion may be desired. I.e., when only `c1 = True` I want the first case to be analyzed; when only `c2 = True` I only want the second case; when both are true, I want the both conditions to be analyzed.

I was thinking about using the following function, but this doesn't work mainly because the new list is not even created.

```
Manipulate[
 Block[{conditional, condlist, c1, c2},
  condlist = {};
  If[c1, Insert[condlist, #[[1]] > 9, -1]];
  If[c2, Insert[condlist, #[[2]] > 3, -1]];
  condlist

   (*Pick[list1, Map[condlist &, list2]]*)
  ], {c1, {True, False}}, {c2, {True, False}}]
```

Anyone has any tips on how I can solve this? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** though the example I present here only considers 2 conditionals `c1` and `c2`, this is to be applied to a much larger set of conditions. It includes 8 conditionals, and may have any combination among it (e.g. `c1 AND c2 AND c4`, or `c7`, or `c5 AND c6 AND c7`, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could thread `Implies` over the conditions and functions.  In this case, I cheated a little, making the functions incomplete.  A boolean `Slot` expression should be entered into an input field.  It is turned into a pure function later, in the code for `pickCriteria`.  I figured you would have to adapt whatever I did to your specific needs anyway, so I just concentrated on getting a working model of the concept.

Use the `criteria` slider to get however many criteria inputs you wish.  Click the checkboxes to turn criteria on or off.

```
list1 = Range[10];
list2 = RandomInteger[10, 10];
maxn = 10;
pickCriteria[cond_, sel_, l_] := 
  ReleaseHold[And @@ Thread[cond \[Implies] sel]] & /@ l;
Manipulate[
 Grid[{
   list1, 
   Thread@Style[list2, 
     pickCriteria[c, funcs, list2] /. {True -> Red, False -> Gray}],
   Pick[list1, pickCriteria[c, funcs, list2]]
   }],
 {{n, 2, "criteria"}, 2, maxn, 1},
 {{c, ConstantArray[False, maxn]}, None},
 {{funcs, ConstantArray[True, maxn]}, None},
 Dynamic@Grid@Take[
    Transpose[{Array[Checkbox[Dynamic[c[[#]]]] &, maxn], 
      Array[InputField[Dynamic[funcs[[#]]], Hold[Expression]] &, maxn]}],
    n]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*The example in the OP.*

```
list1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
list2 = {{9, 0}, {2, 1}, {9.5, 3}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update**

`pickFn` below is a slight improvement on `pickCriteria` above.  It also allows for the satisfaction of your desire "to have a manipulable function" rather literally -- see further on.

```
SeedRandom[2];
list1 = Range[15];
list2 = RandomInteger[10, 15];
maxCrit = 10;

pickFn[cond_, sel_] := Evaluate[And @@ Thread[cond \[Implies] sel]] & /. Hold[x_] :> x;

Manipulate[     
 pickFn[c, funcs],

 {{n, 2, "criteria"}, 2, maxCrit, 1},
 {{c, ConstantArray[False, maxCrit]}, None},
 {{funcs, ConstantArray[True, maxCrit]}, None},
 Dynamic @ Grid @
   Take[Transpose[{Array[Checkbox[Dynamic[c[[#]]]] &, maxCrit], 
                   Array[InputField[Dynamic[funcs[[#]]], Hold[Expression]] &, maxCrit]}],
        n],
 Dynamic @ Framed @
   Grid[{list1,
         Thread @ Style[list2, # /. {True -> Red, False -> Gray}],
         Pick[list1, #]} &[pickFn[c, funcs] /@ list2]]
 ]
```

We can map the `Manipulate` expression `pickFn[c, funcs]` onto another list, via [`Setting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Setting.html), after manipulating the function into the one we want.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While the OP seems to wish to use the function only inside the `Manipulate`, I couldn't resist the call for a "manipulable function."  :)

Comment: Well, I think this answer adds to @Kuba's because of the ability to easily add/remove criteria. This makes it very versatile! Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer may depend of how huge lists you are dealing with.

This is my approach:

```
list1 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
list2 = {{9, 0}, {2, 1}, {9.5, 3}};

Manipulate[
           fcon := Which[c1 && c2, And, c1, #1 &, c2, #2 &, True, False &];
           cond = {#1 >= 9, #2 < 2} & @@@ list2;
           Pick[list1, fcon @@@ cond]
          , {c1, {True, False}}, {c2, {True, False}}]
```

**Edit - general approach to list of conditions**

Without loss of generality I will show it on this example of lists:

```
mainlist = CharacterRange["A", "J"] (*list to Pick from*)
Range@Length@mainlist (*list to test on*)
tests = {NumericQ, OddQ, # < 5 &} (*tests*)
```

> ```
> {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"}
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> {NumericQ, OddQ, #1 < 5 &}
> ```

```
Manipulate[

  Column[{
          TogglerBar[Dynamic@c, Thread[Rule[Range@Length@tests, tests]]]
          ,
          Pick[mainlist, toPick]
         }, Center, Spacings -> 5]


 , {c, None}, ContentSize -> {300, 300}, Alignment -> Center,
 Initialization :> (
     c = {};
     mainlist = CharacterRange["A", "J"]; 
     len = Length@mainlist;
     tests = {NumericQ, OddQ, # < 5 &};
     cond = Outer[Compose, tests, Range@len]; (* I like this part very much :)*)
     toPick := If[c === {}, ConstantArray[False,len], And @@@ (Transpose[cond[[c]]])];
 )]
```

[image]

Description:

`test` - list of tests, I've assumed it is constant but there will be no problem with making it Dynamic

`cond` - array with data if given element fulfills given condition

`toPick` - Since you want to consider only `Conjuntion` of tests we `Apply` `And` to only those results of test that are set by `TogglerBar`.

---

For the example lists in the OP:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[
  {

   TogglerBar[Dynamic@con,
    Thread[
     Rule[
      Range@Length@tests, tests]
     ]
    ],
   Pick[mainlist, toPick]
   }, Center, Spacings -> 5
  ],
 {con, None},
 ContentSize -> {300, 300}, Alignment -> Center,
 Initialization :>
  (
   con = {};
   mainlist = list1;
   len = list2;
   tests = {#1[[1]] >= 9 &, #[[2]] < 3 &};
   cond = 
    Outer[Compose, tests, len, 1];(*I like this part very much:)*)

   toPick := If[
     con === {},
     ConstantArray[False, Length@len],
     And @@@ (Transpose[cond[[con]]])];
   )
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips @kuba! Indeed, this I would like to apply this to much larger lists and conditionals. I believe the size of `list1` or `list2` are not a problem in here, but the number of conditionals may be. I am going to use this to study 8 conditionals which makes it a bit "cumbersome" to write all the possible conditions inside the `Which`

Comment: @Sosi I have no new ideas about the method but I've added general approach, maybe you will find it useful.

Comment: indeed it is useful! Thanks!

Comment: @Sosi if you do not want to try many conditions's combinations then you may consider making `cond` dynamically created. but if you want to check everything and lists are not extremely large you can leave it there.

Comment: yep! I'm now checking out the whole function. I am still not entirely used to `Outer`. Also, `Compose` is equivalent to `Composition`?

Comment: @Sosi No, it is not [look here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28778/why-there-is-no-name-for-12) I'm not used to `Outer` too but I knew it is going to be near there so I've tried couple of things :P