# Apply multiple functions to parts of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

```
data = {{1, a, x, "one"}, {2, b, y, "two"}, {3, c, z, "three"}}
```

I want to apply a list of four functions

```
{f, g, h, m}
```

one for each element of these nested lists respectively. One solution I have come up with is the following:

```
MapAt[m,
 MapAt[h,
  MapAt[g,
   MapAt[f, data, {All, 1}], {All, 2}], {All, 3}], {All, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{f[1], g[a], h[x], m["one"]},
>  {f[2], g[b], h[y], m["two"]},
>  {f[3], g[c], h[z], m["three"]}}
> ```

But I do not consider this an elegant solution because I cannot find a way to escape from the `MapAt` nested repetition. Could you possibly show me the way to generalize the problem and/or suggest a different answer?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question, and thank you all for your answers. I think this is a nice problem to demonstrate how powerful functional programming is with Mathematica and how flexible one can be using any of these functions. I have learned a lot from the comparison of all these approaches to the solution of the problem.

Comment: I knew it had the be here already: [a list of functions onto a list of (lists of) values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/5478)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
data = {{1, a, x, "one"}, {2, b, y, "two"}, {3, c, z, "three"}};
functions = {f, g, h, m};

Inner[#2[#1] &, data, functions, List]

(* Out: 
  {{f[1], g[a], h[x], m["one"]}, 
   {f[2], g[b], h[y], m["two"]}, 
   {f[3], g[c], h[z], m["three"]}}
*)
```

With reversing the order of `functions` and `data`, to fully harness the functional style without using slots:

```
 Inner[Compose, functions, Transpose@data, List]
```

Comment: Just what I was going to post myself… :)

Comment: Great, a very powerful use of the Inner, and yes that generalizes also the problem, thank you MarcoB

Comment: @march why not an answer? p.s. worth to mention `Compose`, [(28779)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28779/5478)

Comment: @Kuba. Right you are! I have added it to my post.

Answer (score 5):

```
data // Replace[#, {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {f@a, g@b, h@c, m@d}, 1] &
```

Comment: Thank you @Sascha, that is nice and clean and definitely shorter than mine ;-)

Comment: If the list is four elements long, there will be a problem. Instead, use `Replace` with a level-spec: `Replace[{{1, a, x, "one"}, {2, b, y, "two"}, {3, c, z, "three"}}, {a_,
    b_, c_, d_} :> {f@a, g@b, h@c, m@d}, 2]`

Answer (score 5):

Not quite as nice and concise as the `Inner` solution, but still worth writing down I think:

```
MapThread[#1@#2 &, {Table[functions, {Length@data}], data}, 2]
MapThread[Compose, {Table[functions, {Length@data}], data}, 2]
```

or

```
MapThread[#1@#2 &, {functions, #}] & /@ data
MapThread[Compose, {functions, #}] & /@ data
```

or

Answer (score 4):

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

MultiMapAt[Transpose[{ConstantArray[All, #], Range@#}]&[Length@functions], functions][data]
```

> ```
> {{f[1], g[a], h[x], m["one"]}, {f[2], g[b], h[y], m["two"]}, 
>  {f[3], g[c], h[z], m["three"]}}
> ```

Which does the same as

```
(Composition @@ MapThread[MapAt, {functions, {{All, 1}, {All, 2}, {All, 3}, {All, 4}}}])@data
```

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{1, a, x, "one"}, {2, b, y, "two"}, {3, c, z, "three"}};
functions = {f, g, h, m};
```

Late for the party:

```
Transpose[# /@ {##2} & @@@ Transpose @ Prepend[data, functions]]
```

Comment: (+1) ... or  `♯ = (# /@ {##2} & @@@ ({#, ## & @@ #2})) &;
♯[functions, data]` :)