# Is Construct introduced to replace Function application? Should it be treated as such an alternative?

Tags: core-language

I noticed that v.11.3 got [*released*](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/03/08/roaring-into-2018-with-another-big-release-launching-version-11-3-of-the-wolfram-language-mathematica/) the other day; it was exciting so I went through the [*Summary of New Features in 11.3*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn113.html) to catch a glimpse of what's new and see if there is something I should keep in mind when writing code, from now on.

There are two new features that caught my attention, namely `Construct` and `Curry`. The later one is marked as experimental, so after skimming through the documentation, I rushed over to `Construct`.

This later symbol seemed promising and as I kept reading the documentation, I was trying to visualize ways to incorporate it in my coding. Eventually, I wrote down each individual use case that-in my understanding-corresponded to the examples in the documentation. I have bundled them together in the end of this question.

It became clear to me that `Construct` is introduced as a more elegant-for lack of a better description-way of... '*constructing*' expressions from base parts (symbols). It seems to render obsolete the need for using raw functions when performing such constructions; imo, the *Applications* section is replete with... '*applications*' of `Construct` that, at one point or another, can become complex enough to warrant the beneficial application of `Construct`.

I was wondering if there are other use cases of `Construct` that didn't occur to me. Can anyone think of other applications of `Construct` where it proves superior to `whatever&@something` or `whatever&@@something` constructs? Is it safe to assume that `Construct` is indeed introduced to address the issues raised in this question? Are there any other ways that it's application might seem productive?

---

```
(* Examples *)

  (* Basic exmaples *)

    f@x === Construct[f, x];

    f @@ {x, y, z} === Construct[f, x, y, z];

    Fold[#1@#2 &, f, {a, b, c}] === Fold[Construct, f, {a, b, c}];


(* Applications *)

  Outer[#1@##2 &, {f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2}, {y1, y2, y3}] === Outer[Construct, {f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2}, {y1, y2, y3}];

  MapThread[#1 @@ {##2} &, {{f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}}] === MapThread[Construct, {{f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}}];

  Inner[#1@#2 &, {f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}, List] === Inner[Construct, {f1, f2, f3}, {x1, x2, x3}, List];


(* Properties and relations *)

  Fold[#2@#1 &, x, {h, g, f}] === Construct[Composition[f, g, h], x];

  f[] === Construct[f];
```

Comment: `Hold@Print[1] =!= Construct[Hold, Print[1]]`

Comment: related: [Is there a name for #1@#2&?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28778/5478)