# Why do I get an error message when for this type of recursion?

Tags: warning-messages, recursion

When I type the following code:

```
mus[] = 0; 
mus[x__] := First[List[x]] + mus[Rest[List[x]]]
```

What one would think would happen is that if,

`mus[1,2,3,4]` is input, the number 10 would be output. However, I get the error message,

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded

However if I use the following code:

```
lsum[{}] := 0; 
lsum[L_] := First[L] + lsum[Rest[L]]; 
sum[x__] := lsum[List[x]]
```

It works as I thought it should, namely if input lsum[x1,x2,x3,...,xn], the output is the sum of the xi's.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thank you. I think that this answers my question.

Comment: Your function is not tail-recursive in the Mathematica sense. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481301/tail-call-optimization-in-mathematica) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21746/what-tools-can-help-in-realizing-tail-recursion) for an explanation.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I have written a tail recursive variant using linkedlists. But on second thought I did not want to bother the OP :). I'll put it in my answer later, as I guess it will trigger the message again when the input is large. Leonid note that this is not a dupe, as what's causing the message in this case is just a conceptual mistake (`{}=!=Unevaluated[Sequence[]]`)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I wasn't one of the closers here, just left a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rest` on a list gives you another list. Even Rest[{1}] gives you a list, i.e. the empty list `{}`. Therefore, in your first code, the second term with the rest in it will always make another call using the definition for `mus[x__]`, which produces another second term, which makes at another call to `mus[x__]` ad infinitum.

Maybe you were thinking of a function like this

```
rest[first_, others___] := others
```

then you can write

```
mus[] = 0;
mus[x__] := First[List[x]] + mus[rest[x]]
```

I'm not saying this is good practice though :).