# How do I define a function that uses a recurrence relation?

Tags: function-construction, recursion

I know how to define functions other than the ones that use a recurrence relation to calculate the $n$-th term of a sequence. How would such a function be constructed?

Comment: The title and the text contradict each other. Anyways, `RSolve` and `RecurrenceTable` might be of interest. Have also a look at `Nest` and `Fold`.

Comment: The first thing you should is search on "recurrence" in the Documentation Center. You also might search on "recursion" on this site.

Comment: You can use Once if you just want to calculate the nth term without repeating previously executed steps.

Comment: @user60620: I just want to translate your `title` as: there is a function `f(x,y)` where `x` or `y` is a `recurrence` relation. This means that `f(x,y)` is a `nested` function, including the recurrence relation. The degree of recurrence should be known. If this clarification reflects what you have, then I can give a simple example.

Comment: This question has already been dealt with a number of times. Here are two previous questions which have answers that might be of interest to you: 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61050/3066 and 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21746/3066

Comment: Marking this as a dupe, unless you edit your question to explain why it's not a dupe. Also, please look up `DifferenceRoot[]`.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
Table[Evaluate[a[n] /. RSolve[{a[n + 1] - 2 a[n] == 1, a[0] == 1}, a[n], n][[1]]], {n, 0, 10}]
(* {1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511, 1023, 2047} *)
```

A construct a function:

```
a[n + 1] - 2 a[n] == 1 -> a[n + 1] == 1 + 2 a[n] -> a[n] == 1 + 2 a[n - 1]
```

and then:

```
a[0] = 1;
a[n_] := a[n] = 1 + 2 a[n - 1]
Table[a[n], {n, 0, 10}]
(* {1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511, 1023, 2047} *)
```